# Is this proper English in this situation?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-choice

> Put on your shirt, change your dress, underwear, ect... I am not looking you, do not be in hurry.

Situation, a girl that is your co worker has to change clothes and putting on new clothes in emergency in the room you are sitting and you turn your head to the wall not looking her and you want to use proper English.

Comment: A better way would be to leave the room and let the girl have her privacy.

Comment: Of course I couldn't agree more but just about English language are these sentences lexically correct thank you in advance

Comment: Lexically?  If I were that girl, I'd rather have my privacy than perfectly correct English and a guy staying in the same room where I need to undress.  Tell her in the broken English that you respect her privacy and leave the girl to call you back when she's done (like, "I'll be just outside, let me know when you're done").

As far as your text, "looking ***at*** you", and "be in ***a*** hurry".

Comment: "I am not looking you" should read "I am not looking at you", though that is kinda creepy as it implies that you are looking.  Instead, "I won't look and please take as much time as you need."  might come off better.  Also, listing individual pieces of clothing, especially intimates, also implies that you really may want to look and should just be avoided mentioning altogether.  Best would be to exit the room completely :)

Comment: What kind of "emergency"? And why would you be directing her to change her clothes?

Comment: @user5036, actions speak better than words in situations like this (I agree with @Victor). One does not simply become a gentleman by using proper English. :insert Boromir here:

Answer (score 3):

"I will go over here/turn this way to give you some privacy."

You could add "take whatever time you need," but unless she knows you well this has a risk of suggesting that you are happy for it to take longer, which could be a little creepy.

Comment: If the concern in your last sentence is for real, then, instead of "take whatever time you need" one might also say "cough when you are decent again". That would also leave the lady in control.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, agreed - or just "let me know when you're ready."  As for the concern being real, yes, but just in this sense:  the part about giving you privacy is less sensitive to tone.  But anything about "don't hurry on my account," "take all the time you need," etc. could come off wrong depending on tone and how well they know each other.